# User's info shown on another user's session

Tags: php, session, cookies, cloudflare

I'm trying to solve a bug on a (poorly written) PHP web app.

**Here is the problem:** As soon as some users log in, the shown dashboard (domain.com/user/) is showing another user's information. If then the user clicks on another section, let's say "pending tasks" (domain.com/user/tasks.php) it shows the proper tasks for the valid session.

**Some clues:**

1. We are using Cloudflare and as far as I understand Cloudflare won't cache dynamic pages but I had to try and I noticed that if I add `?whatever=anythinghere` to the URL it forces to render the page with the proper data and everything works fine.
2. I also noticed that users that always connect from the same place don't have a problem but users that change locations will experience the bug.
3. This app handles session authentication with cookies
4. The original developers are unreachable or simply vanished in thin air
5. Code has a nice amount of comments... in Italian, which I don't capisco niente.
6. They didn't use an MVC, HMVC, MVVM or anything that looks like a pattern.
7. Apparently they didn't like it DRY either.  HEAD section, META blocks, CSS links and JS calls repeat in almost every PHP file.

So far I added manually a `?v=randomstring` to any link in the navigation section but I don't think that is a nice solution.

What do you thing is the problem here?

A. Cloudflare not being properly configured?

B. Using cookies instead of PHP server sessions

C. Something obvious but hidden to my narrow vision.

And, considering the clues and limitations listed above, what would be your approach?

PS.  I know this quite an open question. Maybe also leading to opinion based answers. So I'm open to any suggestion that could make this question very useful to other members.

Comment: This definitely sounds like a poorly written application and the problem could be anywhere. Sounds like it could be a session/cookie thing, but hard to say without some sort of code to look at...it could also be some sort of poorly-implemented html caching system they have created.

Comment: Have you got a local copy working? What happens if you take CloudFlare out of the equation?

Comment: I have a copy on another server without Cloudflare and it works ok but again, as far as I know, Cloudflare won't cache PHP files, right?